# Inserting a record into Access Database

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, insert

I'm having great difficulty in inserting a record to my access database. I've tried the query in access and it inserts fine. I've also tried the query in the query builder and it works too however if I run this code it claims to have inserted the record into the database, but when I check the database there is no sign of a new record.

```
      oleDbCommandCreateAppointment.Parameters["appointmentDate"].Value = "06/04/2012";
        oleDbCommandCreateAppointment.Parameters["timeSlotID"].Value ="21";
        oleDbCommandCreateAppointment.Parameters["startTime"].Value = "09:00";
        oleDbCommandCreateAppointment.Parameters["employeeID"].Value ="1";
        oleDbCommandCreateAppointment.Parameters["clientID"].Value ="1";
        oleDbCommandCreateAppointment.Parameters["assistantID"].Value ="1";
        oleDbCommandCreateAppointment.Parameters["appointmentType"].Value = "Quote";
        oleDbCommandCreateAppointment.Parameters["appointmentFlag"].Value = "Booked";

        try
        {
            oleDbConnection.Open();
            int rows = oleDbCommandCreateAppointment.ExecuteNonQuery();

            MessageBox.Show("Rows inserted " + rows.ToString());

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            oleDbConnection.Close();
        }
```

SQL Command

```
INSERT INTO tblAppointments
                     (appointmentDate, timeSlotID, startTime, employeeID, clientID, assistantID, appointmentType, appointmentFlag)
  VALUES        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Many thanks

Comment: You might want to try naming your parameters, rather than `?`. JET should understand what you're doing. That is, `INSERT INTO ... VALUES (@A, @B, @C)` and then add named parameters (e.g. `@clientID`) to your `OleDbCommand`.

Comment: @ta.spect.is You can't use named parameters with OleDbCommand (I updated my answer with a note about that, it caught me off guard too)

Comment: @pstrjds I'm pretty sure JET does it slightly different. You can say `VALUES (@A, @B, @A)` and you only need to add `@A` and `@B` in order.

Comment: @ta.speot.is it's not the underlying engine that is the issue, you can use named values in Jet, he is using the OleDB connector, that only supports positional parameters. I provided a link in my answer about that.

Comment: @pstrjds Yes, and my recollection is that `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` sort-of-supports named parameters when you're using it through `System.Data.OleDb`.

Comment: @ta.speot.is - It does not support named parameters when the [command type is text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>You need to associate the connection with the db command object:</strike>

```
oleDbConnection.Open();
oleDbCommandCreateAppointment.Connection = oleDbConnection;
int rows = oleDbCommandCreateAppointment.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

EDIT - This <strike>may have</strike> has to do with the parameter ordering, try this:

```
oleDbCommandCreateAppointment.Parameters[0].Value = "06/04/2012";
oleDbCommandCreateAppointment.Parameters[1].Value = "21";
oleDbCommandCreateAppointment.Parameters[2].Value = "09:00";
oleDbCommandCreateAppointment.Parameters[3].Value = "1";
oleDbCommandCreateAppointment.Parameters[4].Value = "1";
oleDbCommandCreateAppointment.Parameters[5].Value = "1";
oleDbCommandCreateAppointment.Parameters[6].Value = "Quote";
oleDbCommandCreateAppointment.Parameters[7].Value = "Booked";
```

NOTE - Something I learned while working on this, you can't use named parameters with ODBC and OleDB commands, only positional parameters (see [Table 6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379620%28VS.80%29.aspx#vsgenerics_topic7)) and this link points out that the [OleDbCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) object only supports positional parameters when the command type is `Text`. Positional parameters are order dependent.

Comment: Done that, but still having the same issue

Comment: From the code you posted it didn't look like you had, can you show more of your code then, the construction of the command object, etc. Are you opening a transaction and not committing it?

Comment: Sorry what I meant by that is I've added what you suggested. My connection object is in the tray area of the form and so is my Insert command.

Comment: Can you post your query at least? How about your connection string as well.

Comment: Parameters are stored in the collection by the way*

Comment: Now getting the error message " parameter ?_1 has no default value"

Comment: That may have been my forgetting to add the '@' symbol

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9760/discussion-between-pstrjds-and-mjsey)